# Perl input to array

Tags: arrays, string, perl, input

I am taking input into an array until the user presses command d. I at first did a while loop but then switched to a for loop which you will see in the comments. Both with the for loop and while loop, the input is only getting put into the array every other. So if I input a b c d e f, then print the array it only outputs b d f. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
print "Please enter your favorite foods, one per line\n";
#my $i = 0;
for(my $i = 0; $foods = <>; $i++){
  #while($foods = <>){
    chomp($foods = <>);
  push(@foods, ($foods));
#    $foods[$i] = $foods;
#}
}

Please enter your favorite foods, one per line
a
b
c
d
e
f
bdf
```

Comment: Each iteration of the loop reads two lines and discards the first (the second read is in the `chomp` line)

Comment: `while (my $food = <>) { chomp $food; push @foods, $food; }` is a more idiomatic approach. Or `my @foods = <>; chomp @foods;`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say 'Please enter your favourite foods, one per line:';

my @food;

while (<>) {
  push @food, $_ if /\S/; # ignore empty input
}

chomp @food;

say join ' / ', @food;
```

Answer (score 2):

The functional problem in the OP code is that the setup for the FOR loop reads from the terminal a value for $foods,

```
for(my $i = 0; $foods = <>; $i++)
```

and then in the body of the loop we read in a new value for it,

```
chomp($foods = <>)
```

The value typed in at the top of the loop is therefore replaced without ever having been used, so you are only pushing those second / fourth / sixth entries onto the array.

You'll get all six values if you change that last code snippet to just `chomp($foods)`.